# Hot reload in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just starting with Xamarin and not sure if there's a way to have hot reload functionality. I installed this NuGet package but it doesn't seem to work.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.HotReload/

Is there way to have hot reloading in Xamarin Forms development?

Comment: did you read the docs?  https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload

Comment: https://www.twitch.tv/videos/441875218 checkout hot reload in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there are 2 options available for Xamarin Forms:

1- The free one: [Xamarin LiveReload](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload)

2- The paid one: [LiveXAML](https://www.livexaml.com/)

**Update (Aug 2019) :**

Xamarin Forms v4 now added live reload feature internally and there's no need for third-party libraries.

Comment: github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload

Answer (score -2):

have you read documentation attentively? Did you install official HotReload visual studio extension?

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer